# Search complex multidimensional array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very complex multidimensional array.

Each item is like (this code shows the var that is pushed to the array):

```
var arrayItem = {
                'itemId': '00001',
                'itemName': 'Biscuits',
                'parentId': 'Food',
                'children': []
            };
```

itemId is always unique. The children array is populated with more `arrayItem`(s). The array can therefore have many levels (possible max 9, but maybe more) - So the base array has x number of objects and each of those can have y number of children objects and so on...

Is there a way to search for a particular `itemId`. I have tried various .each methods but I can't seem to search all of the levels of the multidimentional array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: jquery has nothing to do with this. you are using javascript to do the search, not the DOM manipulation framework

Comment: No loops (or `each` functions) - you have not a multidimensional array, but a *tree*! You will need to use a [tree search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_search_algorithm), which is easier to implement using recursion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**

A few years worth of experience and [`Array` prototype improvements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) later, here's how I'd solve the problem:

```
function find(arr, id) {
    return arr.find(item => item.itemId === id) 
        || arr.reduce((found, curr) => found || find(curr.children, id), undefined)
}
```

This performs a breadth-first search through the object graph, and returns `undefined` if it does not contain the ID you're looking for.

**Original answer:**

```
function finder(arr, id){
    arr = [].concat(arr);
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].itemId == id){
            return arr[i];
        }else if(arr[i].children.length){
            var val = finder(arr[i].children, id);
            if(val){
                return val;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;        
}
```

Pass finder your array and the desired ID, and it will find and return the array item with that id.

Use it like this:

```
var arr = [{
    'itemId': '00001',
        'itemName': 'Biscuits',
        'parentId': 'Food',
        'children': [{
        'itemId': '00002',
            'itemName': 'Sweet',
            'parentId': 'Biscuits',
            'children': [{
            'itemId': '00004',
                'itemName': 'Chocolate',
                'parentId': 'Sweet',
                'children': []
        }]
    }, {
        'itemId': '00003',
            'itemName': 'Salty',
            'parentId': 'Biscuits',
            'children': []
    }]
}];

var chocolate = finder(arr,"00004");
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mVyha/

Comment: I'd suggest to add a usage example to the answer, since you can't pass `arrayItem` from the question as the first argument to `finder`. Otherwise, recursion is the best approach here, my +1.

Comment: Or just add `if (!$.isArray(arr)) arr = [arr];` in the first line, to make it universal.

Comment: @VisioN Done, although slightly differently.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I works well, but seems to return false for any 3rd+ level down item. For example, if Jam had a child.

Comment: `undefined` or `null` is more descriptive for empty result. That was my final note :)

Comment: @Asad Although I promised not to comment, but `return undefined;` is superfluous :) How about `return null;`? Or just erase that line.

Comment: @Patrick I found the problem. Should work correctly now: http://jsfiddle.net/mVyha/2/

Comment: @VisioN Haha okay, fixed. Happy now?

Comment: Wow! Cheers for this @Asad and VisioN. Just adapting into my code now, but seems to be working brilliantly! :)